# Access DB corruption issue, can't find info on similar issue anywhere

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am currently working at a large company on a school placement. The group I am working in supports a fairly complex Access DB which houses a myriad of data, and has 40+ forms. We have been running into a problem that no one (not even the vets) can figure out. I've been asked to search the internet for any info, but can't even find anyone that has even had a similar issue.

Here is the problem:

A bit ago (read: before I got here), the company did an upgrade from Access 03 to 07. Everything was fine. My first task when I arrived was to insert a snippet of code to record which user was making modifications to different DBs (because of the removal of the mdw). This went fine, and we threw the whole thing into production. 
A few days later, we received our first phone call, "Help! I keep getting an error, and can't access the db!" The error was 'The VBA modules in this db appear to have been saved with errors, etc, etc'. We obviously had corruption issues. Funny thing is, when we went into the code for the forms, it was all gone, save for "Option compare DB" at the top of every form. So we had 40+ forms that all said that, and nothing else.
We promply re-upped a backup, no big deal.
Two days later, same thing. Re-up the backup.
This happend a few more times. Not just the same user on the same machine. However, didn't happen to me, or to my mentor.
Then we thought maybe the issue was the way we imported the forms with the new code, so we installed the backup, and copied the forms over one by one.
Next day, same issue.
By this point, we thought that it must be the five lines of code we had added (who knows why), so we just ran with the old backup, no changes.
It's been about two weeks now, no issues. Until this morning. One particular user had this happen four times yesterday (not to any one else).

Anyone ever heard of such a thing? What could possibly be the problem? I'm sure there are a wide variety of possibilities, and I am sure I haven't given enough info to narrow it down much, but I don't know what else to write (never worked with a large Access app before).

I'm obviously stumped, but so are all the clever vets I work with.

EDIT**
For clarity: All of the forms are perfectly fine in terms of their view. I can open them, and they look absolutely normal, just no back end code....

Comment: Is your db split be/fe? Have you decompiled? Created a new db from back-up? Read http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruptmdbs.htm ?

Comment: is this relevant: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-access/corrupt-vba-modules-when-using-access-2007-to-open/5bc586c0-194e-4975-a2ea-0a2775b75e41

Comment: The most common cause of this problem is an unsplit db.

Comment: Definitely have decompiled.... Have created a new db from back-up. Now for my stupid bit..   How do I know if it is split (again, I haven't had too much experience with DBs)? I don't think it is, ie. all users access a shortcut to the same folder on a shared drive. There aren't a ton of users (10-15? - and I'm not suggesting that this makes it ok). I guess it's up to them if they want it split. I figure their issue is that it has never been an issue up until now, and that app has been running for a number of years. Why is this happening now, and not before?

Comment: In a multi-user environment, you **must** use a split db, that is, data in the back-end on the network; forms, reports, etc in the front end on each of the user's pcs, with links to the back-end tables.

Comment: See here : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304932 also http://allenbrowne.com/ser-01.html BTW do not compact on close it is a fatal idea.

Comment: I will check out the links, appreciate all the info Remou... Just after I posted my original question, I ran accross a link that mentioned the 'compact on close' option, I ensured that it was de-selected, it was and always has been. I'm waiting for my mentor to exit his meeting to ask him about this... I'm fairly sure that this db is not split, certainly from what I have seen, and as I mentioned, everyone has a common shortcut to the whole shooting match. Maybe I'm missing something in my green-ness.

Comment: So, by way of update, I checked with the boss. Apparently, it is split. He called it a 'shared split', but it is split. Square one.

Comment: Are all the users on the same front end? Is it an accde / mde?

Comment: They are all on the same front end, yes. Also it is not an accde, but we wrote one and are putting that in place. May I ask what exactly that does? Also, please feel free to put something into an 'official' answer so I can give you the upvote you deserve....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each user should have their own front end, vanishing code is a corruption issue and you are losing all the advantages of a split database if the users do not each have their own front end. you can get additional protection from compiling the front-end into an accde or mde file.

The usual argument against each individual having their own copy is that it is difficult for developers to keep the various copies in synch, but there are several solutions for automatically rolling out updates to users, for example, this one by Tony Toews: http://autofeupdater.com/